# проблема с установкой composer

Tags: php, composer, php7.2

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Устанавливаю composer по [гайду с digitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-18-04) установка просто висит, ничего не происходит.
Ранее он работал, был установлен, но были совершены некие танцы с бубном(удаление, установка, потом снова удаление), после которых возникла такая проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php`
этот способ тоже зависает и ничего не просиходит

Comment: Удалите composer.lock и перезапустите установку. Также просмотрите логи PHP, вероятно там будут намеки на то, что происходит. Можете после скачки файла напрямую запустить его с -vvv флагом для отладки?

Answer (score 0):

https://getcomposer.org/download/1.9.0/composer.phar

Скачайте значит напрямую. Вот последняя версия. Кладете в папку `/usr/local/bin` , например, убираете `.phar` чтоб было удобнее и не забудьте дать права на исполнение. `chmod +x ./composer`

Comment: проблема в зависаниях, сделал, как вы написали, при вызове комманды `composer` ничего не происходит, она просто висит

Comment: А остатки прошлого композера и кеш зачистил полностью после танцев с бубном?